# Does Ionic4 support iOS10?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to build my Ionic4 application for all the iOS devices. It works fine on iOS11 but I wanted to make it work on iOS10 as well, So I tried with all the probabilities.

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@2.3.1 --save-exact

<preference name="deployment-target" value="9.0" />
<preference name="UseScheme" value="true" />
```

Comment: so, what's your problem? 2.x of `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` works fine on iOS 10. BTW, latest is 2.5.1, not 2.3.1

Comment: my ionic4 application runs fine with i-phone 5s onwards [IOS11] but not runs in i-phone5 [IOS 10.3.3] but i want to make it run on all the IOS devices how can i make it happen?

Comment: my Cordova version is 9.0.0 and ionic version is 5.2.3

Comment: thanks man it started working with 2.5.1 plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can try this steps that I done:

1. Downgrade cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to 2.x (2.3/2.5)
2. Change in config.xml
3. In app.component.ts

   setTimeout(() => {
   this.splashScreen.hide();
   }, 1000);

Hope that it will work!